# the best office chat?

Tags: chat, irc

It would be nice to be able to share some code snippets / random stuff with colleagues (15 people).

I was thinking to set-up an office chat, and I wonder if you have any system to recommend.

I can use a dedicated server for that.

Is IRC the way to go? or are there different technologies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openfire server and Pidgin client lets you chat and send files.

Answer (score 1):

IRC is probably a really cheap way of doing this. Pretty much any client can XDCC and send files to other users like, [XChat, chatzilla, pidgin, weechat, mIRC, etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_clients). There's also a free server software that you can setup, like lightIRC, Unreal, Pjirc, Bahamut, etc.

But I think what you really want is project [collaboration software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collaborative_software). There's a lot of options here, some cost money and some are hosted as a service.